# How can I get the 5th root in Java?

Tags: java, methods, root

I am trying for my program to get the 5th root of a number. I have used the `Math.pow(a, b);` method to get this, however it isn't working for some reason.

Lets say I do something like `double z = Math.pow(5, 5)`. I do a `System.out` on this once it gets the value and it will print a result of `3125`. When I do `z = Math.Pow(z, 1/5)` afterwards on it and do a System.out, it doesn't give me a result of 5, but rather 1. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Math.Pow(z, 1/5) evaluates to Math.Pow(z, 0) because 1/5 uses integer division, which rounds down to 0.

Comment: Perhaps 1/5 is calculated using integer arithmetic.  Try Math.pow(z, 0.20D)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try `z = Math.Pow(z, 1.0/5)`

`1/5 == 0` in java

Answer (score 7):

It's because you are doing an integer division: `1/5` is 0 hence the result (x^0 is always 1).

Try: `z = Math.Pow(z, 1.0d/5);`

Answer (score 7):

1/5 rounds to 0 as an integer division.

Try 1.0/5, or just put 0.2.